# CompletableFuture join vs CompletableFuture thenApply

Tags: spring, spring-boot, completable-future

I have this two snippets in a Spring WebMVC controller:

First: `thenApplyAsync`

```java
@RequestMapping(value = {"/index-standard"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public CompletableFuture<String> indexStandard(Model model) {
        return projectService
                .findMine(getCurrentApplicationUser())
                .thenApplyAsync((result) -> {
                    model.addAttribute("projects", result);
                    return "/projectmanagement/my/index";
                });
    }
```

Second: `join()`

```java
@RequestMapping(value = {"/index-nonstandard"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String indexNonStandard(Model model) {
        CompletableFuture<Iterable<ProjectDto>> mine = projectService.findMine(getCurrentApplicationUser());
        CompletableFuture.allOf(mine).join();
        model.addAttribute("projects", mine.join());
        return "/projectmanagement/my/index";
    }
```

For my understanding:

First option:

- `join()` waits for execution of the `CompletableFuture` code.
- the code is executed on a dedicated thread.
- the http thread from the origin http request is available for further requests while the code executes
- at the end (when the code is finished) the view will be rendered

Second option:

- the same as the first option?

What is the difference in these options?

So is there a preferable solution (first or second)?

Both options work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.join()` will block the execution of the thread and wait until the result is ready. Usually, that's not the behaviour one wants when writing async applications.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer a bit? For my understanding "someone" has to wait for the result nevertheless. My rendering engine (thymleaf) has to render the results. So for that the results have to be there. Am i wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Eventually somebody will wait for the result to be ready. But if you use `.join`, you are forcing the choice, potentially blocking one of the available threads. Also, "waiting" can mean different things depending on the async libraries you use underneath.

Comment: My suggestion is to decide if you want your code to be blocking or not and stick with it.

Comment: Thank you. So option one with `thenApplyAsync` would be better?

Comment: I think so, but I think you can just use `.thenApply`